# C# download special character file name files from server

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have  my files in server and file names on DB ....files without special characters I am able to download from server using html download by binding href ....but for special characters file name its not possible to download..please give me suggestion to do...

I have tried using linkbutton ...which I already created controls in aspx page and binding file name to it...but for multiple files its not working ....all files getting single click ...which file is clicked I am not able to get it...please help me in this

Comment: Google URL Encoding

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Url.Encode` to create URL

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/controller/action?filename=@Url.Encode(Model.FileName)">Click Here to download the file</a>
```